# How to use look up table in Google Tag manager when inputs are part of URL?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I wish to create a custom dimension to differentiate if the "condition" is "used" or "new". Let's say I have two following URLs

https://example/**used**/ford

https://example/**new**/ford

I'd like to create a variable in GTM with Look up table. What should I use for `Input Variable` ?

[image]

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is (and has been for some time now) a feature called "[regex table](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/the-regex-table-variable-in-google-tag-manager/)" which does what was asked for.

Previous Answer:

Basically you can't, Lookup Tables look for exact matches.

You would either have to create a variable that extracts the relevant part from the page path, and then feed that variable into the lookup table.

Or you cut out the middle man and do the comparison in a custom javascript variable in the first place.

The inescapable Simo Ahava [has written an article about the latter solution](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/simple-regex-lookup-table-for-google-tag-manager/) (in 2014, no less).

Answer (score 1):

Yea, there's no "contains" logic in a GTM Lookup Table variable.  Only "exact", and I believe it's case sensitive as well.

The solution would be to use a Custom Javascript variable and little regex.

a function like this should do the trick, assuming the pattern from your OP.

```
function() {
   var x = window.location.pathname.match(/^\/(new|used)/i);
   if(x) return x[1];
   return undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the variable called *RegEx Table*

If you go to **Variables** > **User-Defined Variables** -> **New**

Let's give the variable a name like *Car Status*

You can choose variable type **RegEx Table**

Set the Input Variable to **{{Page Path}}**

And to set the rows, you need to the following:

**Pattern**

^/Used/.*

^/New/.*

**Output**

1

2

Under **Advanced Settings**

Check **Ignore Case**, and uncheck **Full Matches Only** and **Enable Capture Groups...**

Now add this variable *{{Car Status}}* where you need it.

This will work on the tracking for a used or new car.

Comment: That feature did not exist when my answer was accepted. However by now this should be the accepted answer.